# How to do a selection sort with linked list

Tags: java

I think I have the basic idea down for the selection sort, but for some reason it's not working and I don't know why? Anyone have an idea what is wrong here?

A few pointers:

.getValue() just returns the object in the node, I'm using integers.

Node tempNode = new Node(null,null,node.getValue()), the first     null is for previous and the second null is for next and the third       just sets the object in the node which is integers in this case.

My input is:
9
5
8
6
10
4

My output is this. For some reason it keeps setting 4 over and over again:
4
5
5
4
4
4

```
 public void SelectionSort()
  {
      Node<T> node2;
      Comparable temp;
      Node<T> Nodemin;

      for(Node<T> node = front;node != null; node = node.getNext())
      {
          Nodemin = node;

          for(node2 = node.getNext();node2 != null; node2 = node2.getNext())
          {
              temp = node.getValue();

              if(temp.compareTo(node2.getValue()) > 0)
              {
                  Nodemin.setValue(node2.getValue());


              } 
              Nodemin = Nodemin.getNext();

          }
          System.out.println(Nodemin.getValue());
          Node<T> tempNode = new Node(null,null,node.getValue());

          node.setValue(Nodemin.getValue());
          Nodemin.setValue(tempNode.getValue());

      }
  }
```

Comment: will look into that , thanks!

Comment: hunch -- it feels like Nodemin = Nodemin.getNext(); should be outside the inner for loop or not there at all. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/selection_sort_algorithm.htm

Comment: Pretty sure not there at all. Compared with https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-selection-sort-for-linked-list/ to be surer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are saying `Nodemin = Nodemin.getNext();`, you are pointing the item to be swapped (the selected item) at the spot beyond where your minimum is. This has an unwanted side effect that when you do the swap, the number you are putting later in the list is going in one beyond the one with which you are swapping it, I believe.

But there is a more subtle flaw in setting Nodemin's value at all as you keep heading down the list and finding lower numbers. Because Nodemin points at a particular location, each time you find a new lowest element, you are not just changing Nodemin's value, but also the value of an item in the list, since they point the same place.

I think you can solve both these problems by changing Nodemin to two separate things, each of which does what you want.

Let minValue be like your temp, tracking the minValue only. Let minLocation always point to where the minValue is (not doing that next line on it ever, just resetting it to where you find a new min).

Then when outside the inner for loop and doing your swap, do it on the place pointed to by minLocation and with the value minValue.

That should fix it. Or it should also work to replace

```
if(temp.compareTo(node2.getValue()) > 0)
          {
              Nodemin.setValue(node2.getValue());


          } 
          Nodemin = Nodemin.getNext();
```

with

```
if(temp.compareTo(node2.getValue()) > 0)
          {
              Nodemin = node2;


          }
```

The suggestions to trace through and debug are good ones. You would see evidence of what I am saying, I believe, and catch any mistakes I am making.

Comment: yeah thanks for the help, i actaully figured that out yesterday just forgot to post it, but thanks anyway!